# How to visualize a Neo4J Graph in python

Tags: python, neo4j

I started to learn Neo4J some days ago for a project. I first launched some Cypher query in my imported Graph (~ 6 million nodes) using Neo4J Browser (I'm working locally with bolt) to test my skills, and the software gives me back the nodes and edges graphically.

Now, I need to launch Cypher queries from Python. I have never used python before so I'm using the official documentation to do this job. I'm using `neo4j` module (from Documentation) to test it and I ran some basic queries successfully.
The problem is: I need to "print" the graph obtained from my queries as Neo4J Browser does, but using Python. I searched on google and I have found different results, sometimes they talk about using JS to draw the graph.
As said, I'm using a single Python file to work and I'm very unexperienced with this language. Could you suggest me a good library to draw nodes and edges resulted from my query?

Right now this is my code:

```
def test(self):
     with self.driver.session(database=self.database) as session:
     session.read_transaction(self._print_nodes)

@staticmethod
def _print_nodes(tx):
     result=tx.run("MATCH (n:cell) RETURN n.name, n.id LIMIT 10")
     for record in result:
         print("ID: ",record["n.id"],"| Name: ",record["n.name"])
```

And this is the result in my console as expected:

[image]

But I want something like this:

[image]

In this case, I changed the query just to print some nodes, but I hope you got what I mean. I'm going to run some queries like N-[E]->M and I need to see the Node N connected through the edge E to the node M in my GUI. If, between the nodes, more nodes are present, I need to print the whole subgraph which connects N to M, with every Node found in the middle.

Answer (score 0):

I found this on the web and it is also supporting neo4j ver 4>=0 so it is very useful.

```
https://github.com/merqurio/neo4jupyter
```

Try installing it first and give it a try. Goodluck.

```
pip install neo4jupyter
```

Comment: How should I implement with neo4j library? I'm not using py2neo, so I don't know how to make it work. As I posted above, I receive a Result object from my cypher query. Then I need something to import relationships and nodes from that result into a graph library and draw it. Another problem is: it wants a label, but I don't use labels, I use the parameter "name" for my queries and I want to display that parameter in the node, not its label. Hope you got what I mean

Comment: Goodluck on your search for an answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

What’s your GUI? If you are using Jupyter  or `Tkinter`I’d suggest using the `Networkx` library to import your graph from Neo4j and output it using `Matplotlib`. But if you want interaction with the graph, you will have to go with a JS library like `Vis`. In fact, I just checked out the other answer and `neo4jupyter` uses `Vis` under the hood. So that would take care of the interaction requirements.

Comment: Seems like I'm not capable of making a graph with NetworkX. I'm using https://www.kaggle.com/yusufbaktir/nxneo4j-tutorial/notebook this documentation. I tried just to draw a graph and it gives me a subgraph of my entire neo4j graph (I just see IDs in my nodes and no labels in edges), but I want to build a graph from my cypher query and visualize it with Network X.