# Is it possible to bring my graphDB from Neo4j to my Jupyter Notebook?

Tags: machine-learning, neo4j

While working on a task, I need to extract graph data from neo4j to the Jupyter Notebook. So, is there any way of doing this.

I had read of using GDS, But I want to do some deep learning things, and I want to do it in jupyter Notebook or any other IDE.

Comment: see also https://stackoverflow.com/q/71147319/10495893

Comment: Yes, this is possible, I have a bunch of examples at: https://github.com/tomasonjo/blogs